# Change decoded value in jwt

Tags: node.js, jwt

Im using json webtoken in a node app. When a user logs in I run this code:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var payload = {};
payload.User = user; //From User table ni database
var token = jwt.sign(payload, 'abcd');
return res.json(token: token);
```

When something happens during life cycle, then something is changed in User table. However, the User-object stored in the signed jwt-payload, is outdated.
I could not find some kind of refresh-method in jwt-library. Do I need to regenerate jwt token and insert the updated user-object? It sounds like a bad solution. So I wonder if there is a way to simply refresh content inside jwt-data.

Answer (score 1):

To get a new token you need to sign a new payload. Changing of a token would be:

1. verifying the old token
2. decoding the payload
3. updating the payload
4. signing the payload to get a new token

Also in your code you have:

```
return res.json(token: token);
```

which I assume is really:

```
return res.json({token: token});
```

or this - using ES2015:

```
return res.json({token});
```

but in any case you need to pass your new token to the client - in the form of the response body like you do in your example, or in a form of a cookie.